# How to update localized variables when page is loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My wordpress site localizes variables and then uses those variables in a javascript file. For example:

```
wp_localize_script('jsfile', 'global', array(
    'home'  => is_page_template('template-home.php')
));
```

And then in my JS I use these variables like so:

```
if (global.home) {
     do something
}
```

I use ajax for my front end of the site so the pages never fully reload when I navigate. When I navigate to a different page, my JS file is reloaded with the same JS script I posted above but the condition `if (global.home) {` is still true although the page I loaded uses a different template. Why is this and how can I fix this so my conditional is updated?

Comment: Are you trying to communicate with javascript using php code?

Comment: Actually the other way around. The purpose of `wp_localize_script` is to use variables set with php, inside of js files. Is what I'm trying to do just impossible without reloading pages?

Comment: Not enough known about how your page works or where you call that or how javascript variable `global.home` is set in page

Comment: `global.home` is set in the php file (the first code snippet in my post).

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the detail around how you're enqueuing the relevant script(s), and what php files you're doing it in?